# How can I get ONLY the items at first level?

Tags: javascript, xml

So, I have this xml

```
<conversation>
    <question>
        <title>I want to get this parent</title>
        <question>
            <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
        </question>
        <question>
            <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
        </question>
    </question>

    <question>and get this one</question>
    <question>and also this one too</question>
</conversation>
```

and I would like to get the  at top level, descending directly from `<conversation>` instead of descending from any other tag... How can I get only those 3 `<question>` nodes?

Comment: So how are you currently accessing the data?

Comment: That´s what I´m trying to do... I already loaded the xml file and I have the whole xml tree, now I need to get those 3 nodes, still reading the docs but I don´t see anything about that (obv. I´m missing that part, pretty sure it´s "there")

Comment: How do you "have the whole tree"? Assuming the XML is parsed into an object, all you need is something like `var qs = xml[0][0];` or `var title = xml.conversation[0].question;`

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get this parent" and"I don´t want to get this one" as to the two `question` child nodes of parent? Are you trying to get the text of the selected nodes?

Comment: Yep, I have the xml parsed into an object.

You can see three <question> nodes at top level, and the first one has more <question> nodes inside. I want to get only the three at top level ignoring the other <question> nodes

Comment: Ok, so console.log() the object and check the hierarchy.

Comment: Use the query selector `conversation > question`

Comment: The hierarchy is ok, simply I don´t know how to get those 3 at top level...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('conversation > question')`

the > means direct child.

[example here](https://jsfiddle.net/487smd6x/) just so there is no confusion:

```js
console.log( 
 document.querySelectorAll('conversation > question')
)
```

```html
<conversation>
  <question>
    <title>I want to get this parent</title>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
  </question>

  <question>and get this one</question>
  <question>and also this one too</question>
</conversation>
```

Comment: The first match will contain child `<question>` nodes?

Comment: OP is asking how to _not_ return the nested child nodes. Your solution does not filter the nested child nodes from return value of `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: that makes no sense. don't iterate over the children. collecting the direct descendants is exactly what the `>` (immediate children) does.

Comment: _"that makes no sense."_ What is the first element matched by the selector you are using?

Comment: `conversation > question` will only match the three top level nodes. if you call into node.children you're using additional DOM capabilities to select the children. That is out of scope of this question imo and a stretch to think OP would explicitly do that.

Comment: You are incorrect. The first match of `document.querySelectorAll('conversation > question')` contains all `<question>` child nodes of parent element `<question>` element. OP wants to exclude the child `<question>` nodes from the return values.

Comment: see the example, the only child nodes are contained within the _children_ property of the parent nodes. they are not being returned by the query, and are ignored unless you explicitly call into them.

Comment: That is not what OP is asking. OP is asking to exclude the child elements from returned result. https://jsfiddle.net/487smd6x/1/ . OP want the text content of the nodes which OP specifically indicated at original Question.

Comment: you're running an additional query. I'll wait for OP to chime in further. IMO you're making assumptions and over complicating things.

Comment: Not making assumptions, asked OP. You are ignoring that fact. Why would OP clearly indicate the text nodes they want to return, and the node they do not want to return at OP?

Comment: and my set can loop over the nodes and collect title text content, dont' query for additional children if you don't want them. hence why you've over complicated things. but again, I'll wait to see what OP wants. This is getting tiresome.

Comment: @guest271314 : check the comments at OP's post. He exactly states _now I need to get **those 3 nodes**._ Using the `>` selector and returning with nodes actually answers his question.

Comment: @KarelG `#text` nodes are nodes. Why did OP clearly indicate which `#text` nodes they want to filter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163246/how-can-i-get-only-the-items-at-first-level/41164222?noredirect=1#comment69530801_41164222 _"I don´t want to get this one"_

Comment: @rlemon You may well be correct. Specifically asked OP if they wanted the text, OP said "Yep". OP will have a solution they can utilize either way.

Comment: @guest271314: The OP asks: _"How can I get only those 3 `<question>` nodes?"_. That's ___exactly___ what this answer does.

Comment: @Cerbrus What did OP mean by _"Yep"_ when asked _"Are you trying to get the text of the selected nodes?"_? Where the `#text` nodes that OP does not want are clearly designated at Question _"I don´t want to get this one"_

Comment: Even if he just wants the text, this selector is how you get the proper nodes.

Comment: @Cerbrus What do you mean by _"how you get the proper nodes"_? That is path took at own own Answer. The present Answer does not filter only those `#text` nodes clearly indicated by OP. Can you explain why the `#text` nodes have _"I don´t want to get this one"_ within them? In any event, was only trying provide another possible perspective for  rlemon.

Comment: @guest271314: Read this _very carefully_: The OP wants to do ___something___ with those top 3 nodes. That means you need to ___get___ those top 3 nodes. Then, if you need the node's text, the next step is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get first-level children of conversation

```
document.getElementsByTagName('conversation')[0].children
```

Comment: This is particularly useful when you have nested <li> <ui>. In the example above if you had nested conversations within questions the solution would fail because 'conversation > question' would find the deep questions.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the top level `<question>` elements, [@rlemon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163540/1835379) is the one you need.

If you want the text from those elements, you'll need to expand his code a little bit:

```js
console.log(
  Array.prototype.slice.call(                            // Convert the `querySelectorAll` result to an array
    document.querySelectorAll('conversation > question') // Get all top question nodes
  ).map(e => e.innerText || e.children[0].textContent)   // Get the element's text, or the element's first child's text.
)
```

```html
<conversation>
  <question>
    <title>I want to get this parent</title>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
  </question>

  <question>and get this one</question>
  <question>and also this one too</question>
</conversation>
```

Comment: Change your perspective, flanking a mate,  elegant solution or all of above?

Comment: @guest271314: Not quite. I still think He just wants the elements, but if he wants the text, your answer isn't exactly the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: Cannot disagree with you on that note. Wanted to be thorough and show the process so OP could have an approach to possibly filter other elements, by checking `.parentElement`, `.filterElementChild` and `.nodeName`s. Not elegant at all. Perhaps OP will chime in. Certainly has an Answer, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"conversation question"`, `Array.from()`, check if current element `.parentElement.nodeName` is `"QUESTION"`, if true return empty string, else check if element has `.firstElementChild` and `.firstElementChild.nodeName` is `"TITLE"`, if true return `.firstElementChild.textContent`, else `.firstChild.textContent`, call `.trim()` on resulting text, chain `.filter()` with `Boolean` as parameter to remove empty strings.

```js
var questions =  Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("conversation question")
  , function(el) {
    return (el.parentElement.nodeName === "QUESTION"
            ? "" 
            : el.firstElementChild 
              && el.firstElementChild.nodeName === "TITLE"
                ? el.firstElementChild.textContent
                : el.firstChild.textContent).trim();
  }).filter(Boolean);

console.log(questions);
```

```html
<conversation>
  <question>
    <title>I want to get this parent</title>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
    <question>
      <title>I don´t want to get this one</title>
    </question>
  </question>

  <question>and get this one</question>
  <question>and also this one too</question>
</conversation>
```

Comment: OP asked how to get the nodes, not the text contents. you've over complicated things.

Comment: @rlemon _"Are you trying to get the text of the selected nodes?"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163246/how-can-i-get-only-the-items-at-first-level/41164222?noredirect=1#comment69527331_41163246, _"Yep"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163246/how-can-i-get-only-the-items-at-first-level/41164222?noredirect=1#comment69527362_41163246.

Comment: you're being selective there and paraphrasing, OP specifically mentions collecting nodes everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if that's what you need, but you put javascript tag.
So here is a JavaScript code which will get you all of  nodes:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('question');
```

Comment: I don´t want all the <question> nodes, only the ones at top level, descending directly from <conversation>

Comment: Therefore just get a first element from the list: var firstQuestion = document.getElementsByTagName('question')[0];